# Key combinations on poll-based input

Tags: input, keyboard, polling

So assume you have an input system that is based on polling

```
void update()
{
    if( Keyboard[ 'A' ] )
        // A is down
}
```

Say you want to be able to recognize 3 to 8 length key combinations (like down, down-forward, forward, A for hado-ken)

How would you best create a generic (easily modifiable/programmable) key combination input system on *polled* input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fundamentally, *you can't*. Key combinations require an ordering, and an ordering requires events.

What you can do is turn polling into events by comparing the key states each frame and generating post-hoc keyup/keydown events from the differences. It's not as reliable because you lose the timestamping and other intra-frame ordering that "native" event systems provide, but it will allow you to detect and order at least one key per frame.

Once you have those ordered events, you can use a finite state machine or other tool to match them against your move lists and execute the correct one.

Comment: It's a little misleading to say that you *can't* do this without events. Technically, events are just a way to call a method or list of methods when some condition is met. In that sense, you need events. However, I can apply the word events (improperly) to many programming tasks that fit that description. I've added an answer that solves the problem in the way that I usually do it, which does not use what most programmers tend to think of as "events".

Comment: Your code does exactly what I said to do without events, but ignores the caveats - which is that you lose intra-frame ordering. When you get events from e.g. the Win32 message loop, you get them in an order with more granularity than a glob per frame. When you compute deltas yourself, you lose that. For a fighting game where players might input several parts of a combo in a single frame, you need to know if those were in or out of order.

Comment: Fair enough. Provided that we're polling at 60hz, I doubt we want to distinguish between presses that are less than the 16ms apart that 60Hz polling provides (assuming our players are humans).

Comment: We do. Skilled fighting game players can enter a hadouken/shoryuken stick command in less than three frames, meaning we must distinguish between them.

Comment: Then you need to poll more often than 60hz.

Comment: Without events it is extremely difficult to poll more than once per frame. That's my whole point.

Comment: It's *not* difficult to poll more than once per frame without events, that's my point. Just run the code I wrote in a separate thread at any loop interval that you'd like (e.g. 120hz) and update the input state. If nothing else can modify the input state, then you don't even need to worry about locking the state (with most modern hardware).

Comment: What library are you using that will update the keyboard state more than once per vsync and lets you run input handling outside your window handling thread, and does not have a more easily-accessible event-based mode?

Comment: XNA. Vsync only affects how often the framework's Update() and Draw() are called on framework instances that inherit those methods. If you have your own loop, it can loop as often as you like. If you request the input state (on the XBOX 360 at least) outside of the framework's update loop, it does not get put into some sort of queue as you seem to suggest. And no, it does not have an event based mode, the model for getting input in XNA is to poll.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to store the current and previous input states, and compare them every time that you poll the input.

For each key that can be pressed, store an object that has a timestamp of the last time that the key switched from a down state to an up state.

Update these objects by doing this at every poll:

```
void update(){
    some_key_has_been_pressed = false;
    foreach(key in keys){
        if(previous_input[key].Down && current_input[key].Up){
            keys[key].up_timestamp = current_time();
        }

        if(current_input[key].Down){
            keys[key].down_timestamp = current_time();
            some_key_has_been_pressed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can pattern match your combos against the contents of `keys`.

Have a combo object for each combo, and call update() on each combo object at each poll.

A combo object's update() method will pattern match the combo, checking if all necessary conditions for the combo are satisfied at this poll. I.e. all keys timestamps for the combo so far are in order, and no other key that would break the combo has been pressed this frame. For each condition met, increment a counter in the combo object to the next condition to check. When all conditions are met in a combo, call the method that the combo should perform.
If `some_key_has_been_pressed == true` but the key that is the next condition for the combo has not been pressed, then reset the combo's satisfied condition counter to 0.

The above is my preferred method, as it is simple to implement, easy to maintain, efficient, and highly modular.

However for another good method, check out the [XNA input sequence sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/input_sequence_sample), which is written in C#, and the logic is likely transferrable to the language you're using.

Comment: In the second if-statement, `if(current_input[key].down){`, wouldn't you also want to check if the key was up in the `previous_input` state?  As written, I think it would continuously update a held key's `down_timestamp`.

Comment: Continuously updating the down timestamp is the intended behavior. This allows you to compare the up_timestamp and down_timestamp of any key, to check how long it was held for. 

If you continuously hold a key, you are not changing the up_timestamp, so (down_timestamp - up_timestamp) still gives you the duration it was held for.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  I was thinking the opposite, where up_timestamp - down_timestamp is the duration of a held key.

Answer (score 1):

Make a stack of the last X key events, for each key event add an object with the key and time of the press/release, then check if the last members of the stack match a special pattern and if those keys were pressed fast enough to count as a combination. Finally remove the oldest object from the stack.

Comment: A stack that you can remove the bottom object from is not really a stack ;)

Comment: An ordered bunch of data entities, a list might be the correct term.

Comment: deque ;) O(1) enq/deq ftw.

Comment: An ordered sequence where objects are put onto one end and removed from the other is most properly called a _queue_.

Comment: You can make a ring-buffer (BufferLength >= longest command) and write keys to it (Position = Number MOD BufferLength). No adding/removing will be required at all

Comment: (By the way, -1 because you presuppose key events and the entire purpose of the question is how to do it without them.)